# Functions that recursively reference themselves in Swift

Tags: xcode, recursion, swift

Recursive functions currently cause compile-time error in xcode projects using swift, but work just fine in a playground. In the release notes of Xcode 6 beta 4 :

> Nested functions that recursively reference themselves or other
>   functions nested in the same  outer function crash the compiler.
>   (11266246) For example:
>
> ```
> func foo() {
>   func bar() { bar() }
>   func zim() { zang() }
>   func zang() { zim() }
> }
> ```
>
> Workaround: Move recursive functions to the outer type or module
>   context

What is meant by Move recursive functions to the outer type or module context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you should declare the function outside of the other function:

```
func bar() { bar() }
func zim() { zang() }
func zang() { zim() }
func foo() {
}
```

Comment: Does that mean that a recursive function that is called in viewDidLoad() should be declared outside of it?

Comment: @Carpsen90 that is correct (until they fix the bug at least)